# Most efficient way to determine CouchDB access permission

Tags: couchdb

I'm using the CouchDB permission system with per-db-and-user access rights. Each DB represents an app, which are being displayed in a home-screen-like overview and in other places. I need an efficient way to make CouchDB tell me whether a user has access to a db or not - for example a `GET /_all_dbs` that only returns the DBs for which current user has access. Polling a view or document turns out to be too slow once there are more than a dozen or so apps to display on one page, although I could still tune a view poll with limit=1. Isn't there a better way though?

Answer (score 4):

Query the `_security` document of the database.

`curl http://localhost:5984/db_name/_security`

`{"admins":{"names":["dbadmin"],"roles":["reader"]},"members":{"names":[],"roles":[]}}`

For every database that has admins/users couchdb has a creates a special document called `_security` that holds a list of all the users for that database. You can make a curl request to that document and get an array that will give you all the `admins` and `members` for that database.

**Edit**

You know your application best but here is a strategy that I think could be helpful? Every couchdb user is stored in the `_users` database.  It is just like any other database. You can create a view on it and then query it. You can even add additional fields to the documents to help with querying. How about when you create a user on a database you update the corresponding document in the `_users` database as well.

Now if you call  `_users/_all_docs?include_docs=true` you get a list of users along with the databases they have access to. One request and you have everything you need.

Comment: Thanks. It's still not quite an ideal solution since 1) it's probably not going to be faster than polling a view since it's still one request per DB and 2) one basically has to reimplement the code that CouchDB uses to check whether a user has access or not - which is thankfully not much, since couchdb doesn't have sophisticated read access permissions.

Comment: I am not sure in that case what is the best approach. One thing I would like to add is that if you have created a view then you can query it with multiple keys at once.  Can you share the view that you are using currently to query?

Comment: Querying multiple keys is not going to help - one view query can, as far as I know, only go to one DB - if you need to check access against 20 DBs you will have to do 20 requests. 

Here's what I'm going to do:
1) Cache the accessible applications in the user's session.
2) Wipe this session state at Login, such that I don't need to implement a Cache update mechanism that's too complex.

Comment: All right. You know if it does not sound too complex I have another suggestion. It is too big for the comment so I am going to add it in the answer. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It's an interesting idea. I'd say it makes sense to do this if you a) don't use roles to give database access to users and b) never leave the members field empty such that access is always restricted, i.e. if you always assign all the users you want to give access directly to the members and admin fields. However, in a general case where roles are used and/or access can be left open to all users, it's quite a complex update code you're going to have with your suggestion - hence why I won't use it in my case.